# What is the SQL command to form one to one relationship between two tables?

Tags: sql, database, derby

I am trying to create one-to-one relationships between the a User and Archive table. I successfully achieved that using entity relationship diagram, but not in actual SQL code.

[image]

I wan to create these tables using SQL code like shown below, but at the same time defining its relationship with Table 2.

CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    Some code

);

Comment: Are you thinking of a foreign key constraint?  What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Derby. Basically, I have two tables called user and archive. I know their relationship is one to one, but I don't know how to translate that in SQL. Please help

Comment: I was not familiar w/ derby until this moment.  I'm still not quite sure of what you're asking however.  If you are trying to select records via sql you would use an `inner join` if you are trying to maintain database integrity by enforcing that there is always a 1 to 1 relationship you would use a foreign key constraint.

Comment: [This link](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj24513.html) was my first google hit.  It shows pretty standard ansi sql create table code.  It has a great page on [constraints](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html#rrefsqlj13590)  You are looking at adding something like this: `REFERENCES table2(some_id_column)` as shown in the 6th example.